The query performs significantly slower when executed from ASP.NET MVC web app compared to directly on SQL Server
I am experiencing a notable performance issue with a SQL query when it is executed from an ASP.NET MVC web app compared to running it directly on the database.
The query is supposed to retrieve approximately 40,000 rows, and when run directly on the database, it completes in about 5 seconds.
However, when the same query is executed from my web app using the following C# function, it takes about 23 seconds to complete.
Why is there such a big difference?
Steps already taken:

Query verification: I've checked the query logging to ensure that the web app sends the query correctly, including datatype consistency, and everything appears as expected.
Data transformation: to determine if data transformation was slowing things down, I modified the function to convert all columns directly to strings, bypassing any specific checks for date/time columns like ek_start_datetime. This change only improved the performance by about 1.5 seconds.

public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetData(List<string> columns, string query)
{ 
    List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.CommandTimeout = 200;

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                if (rdr[column] == null)
                {
                    dict.Add(column, "");
                }
                else if (column.Contains("ek_start_datetime"))
                {
                    dict.Add(column, ((DateTime)rdr[column]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                }
                else if (column.Contains("_startdatetime") && DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(rdr[column]), out DateTime res))
                {
                    dict.Add(column, ((DateTime)rdr[column]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                }
                else if (column.Contains("_datetime") && DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(rdr[column]), out DateTime res2))
                {
                    dict.Add(column, ((DateTime)rdr[column]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                }
                else if (column.Contains("_date") && DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(rdr[column]), out DateTime result))
                {
                    dict.Add(column, result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(column, Convert.ToString(rdr[column]));
                }
            }

            data.Add(dict);
        }
    }

    return data;
}

Edit
The query I sent is a string with the global layout of:
SELECT 
    tv.column1, 
    tv.column2, 
    -- ...
    tv.column80, 
FROM 
    table1 tv
WHERE 
    tv.actual_flag = CAST(1 AS INT)
    AND tv.theme = CAST("theme1" AS varchar(10))
    AND tv.year as CAST(2024 AS INT)

When I perform this same query in SSMS and look at the query plan, it is correctly optimized

Does this answer your question? Query extremely slow in code but fast in SSMS

Are you using SqlParameter that you are not showing in your question?

If you just time the executereader and the loop without setting the values or doing any ifs, do you still get bad execution time? SSMS cheats and doesn't fetch whole LOB fields, so that might explain some of the difference. I'm not a bit fan of your dictionary code either, but how does it look if you remove it altogether

@ThomA I checked but sadly no.. I casted the variables in my where statement to the right type but this did not change anything

@Liero No, the query is a string I use directly, no SqlParameters here

@siggemannen I looked into you test but still get an execution Time of 23204 ms.. so I doesnt appear to be in the dictionary code

Then you're leaving some details on the difference between query in SSMS and c#, especially if you don't use parameters in neither queries. Add a trace and capture both variants to see how query plan differs

What about network time to transfer the results? Add to that, can a user realistically handle that many records at once? Could you paginate?

@siggemannen I can see the query that is performed on the database from my webapp via query logging and that does not seem different. It is a simple
Select *
From XXX
where x = cast(y as int)
and z = cast(a as string). How can I see the query plan from my asp.net app?

Ok, but do you have any large fields with a lot of data? Otherwise I'm sorry to say, I don't know

@siggemannen you mean in the response, that could indeed be the case, the result could yield some pretty long strings ..

Yes, that can explain that ssms is fast, because it usually truncates long data

@siggemannen I checked and the column with the longest field has a length of 49 characters .. so not overly long. What it is interesting, when I only pick up a single column the query from the webapp is much faster

Following SET options has potential to affect plan resuse
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET ARITHABORT ON
GO

Following two statements are from msdn - SET ARITHABORT

Setting ARITHABORT to OFF can negatively impact query optimization leading to performance issues.
The default ARITHABORT setting for SQL Server Management Studio is ON. Client applications setting ARITHABORT to OFF can receive different query plans making it difficult to troubleshoot poorly performing queries. That is, the same query can execute fast in management studio but slow in the application.

To set your database to this you can use this in SSMS just once
USE master 
ALTER DATABASE [your_database_name] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT 


Would I simply add this to the beginning of my query?

Sadly these settings do not help either ..

I edited my answer to include the command you need to use in SSMS to get this setting to on

I checked but this had no influence on the runtime

Well it was worth a try, it worked for me when I had the same problem. Hope you will find a solution
